# JSON ParseError when passing a string in single quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am making an ajax post passing along a json object with a string with commas in it. When I make the ajax call, I am getting this in the rails logs:

`JSON::ParserError (822: unexpected token at ''"Word1","Word2","Word3"''):`

The data object I'm sending looks like this:

`{obj: { obj1: '"Word1", "Word2", "Word3"'}}`

When I try to send it without the wrapped single quotes the unexpected token error happens at the comma.

`JSON::ParserError (822: unexpected token at ',"Word2","Word3"''):`

Can anyone decipher the error message? Is there a way I need to encode when passing along via ajax?

Comment: Can you please provide your ajax call in question

Comment: What does the raw JSON look like? JSON uses double quotes for strings (and only double quotes), looks like you might have your quotes mixed up or perhaps improperly escaped.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out the problem was actually needing to escape the special characters and that the datatype to where obj1 was being saved was registering as json vs string. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your data object is wrong. `{obj: { obj1: '"Word1", "Word2", "Word3"'}}` is not even valid. You must have a value for each key.

If `obj1` is supposed to be an array, it must have the `[]` key. Following is an valid JSON example:

```
{
  "obj": {
    "obj1": ["Word1", "Word2", "Word3"]
  }
}
```

To validate your JSON and avoid wasting time with this kind of error, please check your data object [here](https://jsonlint.com)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I tried with both to no available. However, turns out the issue was with escaping characters.